# HDD error: print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 16128

Tags: hard-drive, fat32

I believe I have a USB hard drive that's damaged. When I run `dmesg`, it shows:

```
[80489.847168] ---[ end trace 66bad045bd32e5be ]---
[80577.323943] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[80577.434010] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2329
[80577.434016] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[80577.434020] usb 2-1.1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[80577.434024] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[80577.434028] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: F8B08539621E
[80577.434862] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[80577.436400] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 2329: 8020
[80577.436468] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[80578.445148] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MD02500- AVDW-RO          01.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[80578.446026] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[80578.446441] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[80578.447457] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[80578.447465] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[80578.448565] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[80578.448574] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[80578.485832]  sdb: sdb1 < sdb5 >
[80578.489329] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[80581.790218] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[80581.790223] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[80581.790225] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[80581.790229] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 3f 00 00 00 08 00
[80581.790232] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 16128
[80584.135828] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[80584.135837] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[80584.135843] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[80584.135852] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 3f 00 00 00 08 00
[80584.135856] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 16128
[80584.135867] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 0, async page read
[80584.135875] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 1, async page read
[80584.135880] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 2, async page read
[80584.135885] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 3, async page read
[80584.135890] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 4, async page read
[80584.135941] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 5, async page read
[80584.135961] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 6, async page read
[80584.135977] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb5, logical block 7, async page read
```

I read this [article](http://www.sj-vs.net/forcing-a-hard-disk-to-reallocate-bad-sectors/) that says you can forcibly reallocate bad sectors:

```
$ sudo hdparm --read-sector 16128 /dev/sdb5
/dev/sdb5: Device /dev/sdb5 has non-zero LBA starting offset of 16128.
Please use an absolute LBA with the /dev/ entry for the raw device,   rather than a partition or raid name.   
/dev/sdb5 is probably a partition of /dev/sdb (?)   
The absolute LBA of sector 16128 from /dev/sdb5 should be 32256   
Aborting.
```

I'm lost with what to try next to access the data from this drive.
Can anyone help?

SMART information below:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     MD02500-AVDW-RO
Serial Number:    FXB0XKS96R1E
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 600ec4c15
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 22 16:06:55 2020 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 6600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  79) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   253   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   183   179   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1850
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       75
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       73
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       70
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   120   106   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   051    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Is this a HDD or SSD? Did this drive used to work? Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app `SMART Data` window for that drive. Also, in `terminal` and show me if there's any output to `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Its a HDD.  It use to work.  Potentially it may have been disconnected while idle rather umounted (from a windows pc).   no values returned from the grep command.  Also updated question with smart device informaiton.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that's just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

You have one or more bad sectors on your HDD, as seen by:

```
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       13
```

You need to `fsck` to check your file system, and then bad block your HDD.

**fsck**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

**bad block**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
         read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
         inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
         running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: Thanks.  i guess i can ignore the boot CD?  as its not my boot disk that has the problem.  Its my USB data drive.

Comment: @resolver101 As long as you unmount it first, you don't need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device

Comment: @heynnama See the responce above.  The usb drive is FAT foramtted.  Does that make a difference to the command?

Comment: @resolver101 The USB is FAT formatted? Why? It should be ext4 or NTFS, depending on if you're sharing files with Windows. Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted` view of... is it sdb? Exactly what `fsck` command did you type?

Comment: @resolver101 Status please...

Comment: Sorry, ive been waylayed due to the virus.  I will get back to this as its important to me.

Comment: @resolver101 Best wishes for a quick recovery.